# Using Here3+ for GNSS information, missing documentation?

Tags: can, drone, gnss

The Here3+ is a GNSS receiver often used by drones, specifically the pixhawk. I wanted to use this receiver in my own project for geopositioning, I am however completely unable to find any documentation on how to read its data. I have a CAN connection set up, but it doesn't send anything legible like when using NMEA. And I really don't want to try reverse engineering it by observing what the pixhawk and the Here3+ communicate with eachother. Am I just bad at google? What steps should I take to make this work?

Comment: Have you checked the [DroneCAN Specification](https://dronecan.github.io/Specification/1._Introduction/)?